# Should I pass viewModel or only model to view to upload image/Pdf Document in swiftui in MVVM?Do I need to keep progress for each document?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, closures, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a situation Where I can add multiple images or videos URLs in Array 1 by 1. Similarly, a separate View (AssetView) is modified based on the array elements added. Now, the status of the Image/Video/PDF upload is changed and needs to reflect the progress upload and progress done. But here, I am unable to use MVVM.
I am confused about where should I call the upload function.
Should I pass viewModel to asset View or only view??
I am adding the Source code below to show my problem.

This is the first Screen where the user will get an option to show the card. On Card, the User can select Image/Video/Pdf any document.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: {
                    cardShown.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Show Card")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                })
                BottomCard(cardShown: $cardShown, height: 400, content: {
                    CardContent()
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CardContentView, Where the user will add documents.

```
enum ActionType {
    case ImageButtonAction
    case VideoButtonAction
    case None
}

struct CardContent: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var image: Image? = Image("UserProfilePlaceholder")
    @State private var shouldPresentImagePicker = false
    @State private var shouldPresentActionScheet = false
    @State private var shouldPresentCamera = false
    @State private var galleryAssetTypeSelected = GalleryAssetType.None
    @State private var actionType = ActionType.None
    @StateObject var messageAttachmentViewModel = MessageAttachmentViewModel()
    // Document
    
    @State private var shouldPresentDocumentPicker = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Photo Collage")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .padding()
            
            Text("You can create awesome photo grids and share them with all of your friends")
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .frame(height: 40)
            
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<self.messageAttachmentViewModel.commonMessageAttachmentModel.count, id: \.self) { i in
                            AssetView(messageAttachmentViewModel: messageAttachmentViewModel, index: i)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .frame(height: 140)
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.shouldPresentActionScheet = true
                    self.actionType = .ImageButtonAction
                }, label: {
                    Text("IMAGE")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.shouldPresentActionScheet = true
                    self.actionType = .VideoButtonAction
                }, label: {
                    Text("VIDEO")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.galleryAssetTypeSelected = .PDF
                    self.shouldPresentDocumentPicker = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("PDF")
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("500")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("SEND")
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: self.shouldPresentCamera ? .camera : .photoLibrary, image: self.$image, isPresented: self.$shouldPresentImagePicker, galleryAssetType: $galleryAssetTypeSelected, messageAttachmentViewModel: messageAttachmentViewModel)
        }.actionSheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentActionScheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Choose mode"), message: Text("Please choose your preferred mode to set your profile image"), buttons: [ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Camera"), action: {
                self.shouldPresentImagePicker = true
                self.shouldPresentCamera = true
                self.galleryAssetTypeSelected = .None
            }), ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(actionType == ActionType.ImageButtonAction ? "Photo Library" : "Video"), action: {
                self.shouldPresentImagePicker = true
                self.shouldPresentCamera = false
                self.galleryAssetTypeSelected = (actionType == ActionType.ImageButtonAction) ? GalleryAssetType.Photo : GalleryAssetType.Video
                self.galleryAssetTypeSelected = actionType == ActionType.ImageButtonAction ? .Photo : .Video
            }), ActionSheet.Button.cancel()])
        }
//        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentDocumentPicker) {
//            DocumentPicker(isDocumentPickerPresented: $shouldPresentDocumentPicker, galleryAssetType: $galleryAssetTypeSelected, commentAttachments: $commentAttachments)
//        }
    }
}
```

Below is Image Picker Struct to select Image/Video from Gallery.

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    @Binding var image: Image?
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var galleryAssetType: GalleryAssetType
    @ObservedObject var messageAttachmentViewModel: MessageAttachmentViewModel

    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerViewCoordinator {
        return ImagePickerViewCoordinator(image: $image, isPresented: $isPresented, galleryAssetType: $galleryAssetType, messageAttachmentViewModel: messageAttachmentViewModel)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        pickerController.delegate = context.coordinator
        if galleryAssetType == .Photo {
            pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        } else if galleryAssetType == .Video {
            pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
            pickerController.videoQuality = .typeHigh
        }
        return pickerController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        // Nothing to update here
    }
    
}

class ImagePickerViewCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {
    
    @Binding var image: Image?
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var galleryAssetType: GalleryAssetType
    @ObservedObject var messageAttachmentViewModel: MessageAttachmentViewModel

    init(image: Binding<Image?>, isPresented: Binding<Bool>, galleryAssetType: Binding<GalleryAssetType>, messageAttachmentViewModel: MessageAttachmentViewModel) {
        self._image = image
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self._galleryAssetType = galleryAssetType
        self.messageAttachmentViewModel = messageAttachmentViewModel
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.image = Image(uiImage: image)
        }
        
        if galleryAssetType == .Photo {
            if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerImageURL") ] as? URL {
                let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")] as? UIImage
                let messageAttachmentModel = MessageAttachmentModel(assetType: .Photo, assetUrl: imageURL, image: image, uploadStatus: false)
                self.messageAttachmentViewModel.commonMessageAttachmentModel.append(messageAttachmentModel)
            }
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.image = Image(uiImage: image)
            }
        } else if galleryAssetType == .Video {
            if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL") ] as? URL {
                let messageAttachmentModel = MessageAttachmentModel(assetType: .Video, assetUrl: videoURL, uploadStatus: false)
                self.messageAttachmentViewModel.commonMessageAttachmentModel.append(messageAttachmentModel)
            }
        }
        self.isPresented = false
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.isPresented = false
    }
}
```

This is VideoThumnail View to show only thumbnail after selection. The actual video has to be uploaded to the server.

```
struct VideoThumbnail: View {
    
    private enum LoadState {
        case loading, success, failure
    }
    
    private class Loader: ObservableObject {
        var videoThumbnail = UIImage()
        var state = LoadState.loading
        
        init(url: URL) {
            if url.pathComponents.isEmpty {
                self.state = .failure
                return
            }
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
            let avAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            avAssetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            avAssetImageGenerator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

            let thumnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
            do {
                let cgThumbImage = try avAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumnailTime, actualTime: nil)
                self.videoThumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgThumbImage)
                self.state = .success
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.state = .failure
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    var loading: Image
    var failure: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    init(url: URL, loading: Image = Image(systemName: "photo"), failure: Image = Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")) {
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
        self.loading = loading
        self.failure = failure
    }
    
    private func selectImage() -> Image {
        switch loader.state {
        case .loading:
            return loading
        case .failure:
            return failure
        default:
            return Image(uiImage: loader.videoThumbnail)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is PDFThumbnail View.

```
struct PdfThumbnailView: View {
    
    private enum LoadState {
        case loading, success, failure
    }
    
    private class Loader: ObservableObject {
        var pdfThumbnail = UIImage()
        var state = LoadState.loading
        
        init(url: URL) {
            if url.pathComponents.isEmpty {
                self.state = .failure
                return
            }
            let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)
            if let pdfDocumentPage = pdfDocument?.page(at: 1) {
                pdfThumbnail = pdfDocumentPage.thumbnail(of: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), for: PDFDisplayBox.trimBox)
                self.state = .success
            } else {
                self.state = .failure

            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    var loading: Image
    var failure: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    init(url: URL, loading: Image = Image(systemName: "photo"), failure: Image = Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")) {
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
        self.loading = loading
        self.failure = failure
    }
    
    private func selectImage() -> Image {
        switch loader.state {
        case .loading:
            return loading
        case .failure:
            return failure
        default:
                return Image(uiImage: loader.pdfThumbnail)
        }
    }
}
```

MessageAttachmentModel: This Model is created when Image/Video/Pdf is selected.

```
struct MessageAttachmentModel {
    var assetType = GalleryAssetType.None
    var assetUrl: URL
    var image: UIImage?
    var uploadStatus: Bool
    
    init(assetType: GalleryAssetType, assetUrl: URL, image: UIImage? = nil, uploadStatus: Bool) {
        self.assetType = assetType
        self.assetUrl = assetUrl
        self.image = image
        self.uploadStatus = uploadStatus
    }
}
```

MessageAttachmentModelView: This ModelView contains an array of MessageAttachmentModel as a published property to reflect the change.

```
class MessageAttachmentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var commonMessageAttachmentModel: [MessageAttachmentModel] = []
    @Published var isUploadedLeft: Bool = false

    func getIsUploadedStatus() {
        let leftToUpload = commonMessageAttachmentModel.filter({ $0.uploadStatus == false })
        isUploadedLeft = (leftToUpload.count > 0) ? true : false
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        for var model in commonMessageAttachmentModel {
            if model.uploadStatus == false {
                if let endUsedId = getEndUserDataId(), let data = getDataFromURL(url: model.assetUrl) {
                    let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                    let key = "u_me_\(endUsedId)_\(timestamp))"
                    var assetType =  (model.assetType == .Photo) ? ("Image") : ((model.assetType == .Video) ? "Video" : "Files")
                    uploadFileData(assetType: assetType, key: key, data: data) { status, urlString in
                        if status {
                            model.uploadStatus = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func uploadFileData(assetType: String, key: String, data: Data , completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void ) {
/// Server Data Upload
    }
    
    func getEndUserDataId() -> String? {
        var endUserId: String?
        return "5"
    }
```

I have to show the progress of Image/Video/Pdf upload on Asset View. I am unable to identify how can I achieve it.

I am adding a simulator screenshot also to understand the situation clearly.

[image]

I am struggling to identify that do I need to keep progress for each document? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to use a ProgressView?

Comment: I know about progress view. But i am confuse where should i call the upload function.